# Using exceptions for validating format of input from the Internet

Tags: exception, networking

It is often said to use exceptions only on handling truly *exceptional* situations.

How about when processing data received from the Internet?  The data is meant to be sent by a conforming client - in which case, no exception will be thrown.

But doing so gives me the feeling that sending a few malformed requests to my application will cause much more server load, which makes it pretty easy to DDoS my server.  Should I be worried about this?

Here's some C++ code to illustrate what I am doing, but I would expect it would apply to other compiled programming languages too.

```
try {
    uint64_t id = stoull(stuff_from_the_internet);
}
catch (...) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: How are you sure that a malformed request will cause much more server load than a conforming request? A conforming request almost always loads cpu much heavier than a simple exception throw.

Comment: I am not sure.  I asked this question because I was writing a server and no one on the Internet mentioned this at all.